# How to logrotate in any user dir as user?

Tags: files, logs, backup, logrotate

We have one file, need to timestamp it and archive it in order to prevent overwrites.

Solution must work in any user directory.

Solution must be foolproof.

Solution should work without superuser commands.

Comment: `man 8 logrotate`

Comment: What have you tried?